after upgrade magnento 2 version 2.4.3 to 2.4.6-p6
recently i was upgrade magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.6-p6 for upgrade i fire below cmd
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6-p5 --no-update
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
after install latest version when i run setup:upgrade it will throw error
There is an error in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php at line: 50
Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\StoreThemesResolverInterface#0 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Theme\M...')
#1 vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Config/Customization.php(75): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Theme\M...')
#2 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Theme\Model\Config\Customization->__construct(Object(Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager), Object(Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design\Proxy), Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\ThemeProvider), NULL)
i went to upgrade my magento version 2.4.3-p2 to 2.4.6-p5

Are you sure this problem is in any way directly related to Composer, or to [tag:frameworks]? What have you tried to resolve it?

Check your /app/etc/di.xml and add in any missing  lines from the Magento 2.4 default https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/etc/di.xml.
Specifically, in your case, make sure <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ResolverInterface" type="Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Resolver" /> is present.
